# Is there a way to make a edge to edge connection only using external magnets and gold fingers?

Tags: pcb, connector, magnet, edge-connector

This question might sound pretty stupid, but I have been searching for solutions for a few days, so all of your new ideas are highly approsciated.

I am on a hunt for a solution for modularly connecting magnetic blocks (for example cubes with a connection on 4 sides out of 6).

The solution needs to be pretty cheap (let´s say max 1 dollar for the four sides), I want it to connect just by a few magnets snapping together. The connection is needed for 4 pins - 2 for power, 2 for data. Let´s say max 5V 0.5A on the power lines and I2C data on the other two.

The connection is straight forward (+ to +, SCL to SCL, SDA to SDA, GND to GND).

I was thinking about using pogo pins with external magnets in my enclosure, but there is always a female and male side.

I was wondering if you have a suggestion, how to make "hermaphroditic" board to board connection on the cheap.

[image]

If there was a way to make something like this using only PCBs and magnets in some kind of an enlosure it would be perfect.

Also is there some way to connect two PCBs just by force pressing two pads together.

If you´d like me to clarify something, please tell me.

Comment: Put both pogo pins and contact pads on both sides?

Comment: Yep, thank you for that suggestion. That would be a bit more expensive and I´m looking for more options. Cool idea.